# C++ atoi() only returns the first digit

Tags: c++, string, int, atoi

I am experiencing a strange problem with atoi()

I am doing a conversion like this:

```
cout<<atoi(mystring.c_str())<<endl;
```

mystring is a string with something like 3245524

The above code would only return 3 to the stdout.

Now, if I make the string smaller, e.g. less than 1000000, then I get the entire number returned to stdout.

Any ideas what is causing this problem? This is still well below the limit of C++ int so it is not some overflow.

EDIT, some additional information. When I simplify the command to simply:

```
cout<<mystring.c_str()<<endl;
```

The stdout is something like 3.24552e+06

Is the problem related to this?

Comment: Present a complete compileable example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: So, according to your edit, `mystring` is in fact nothing like "3245524"

Comment: yes the . will end atoi after 3

Comment: Where does atoi come into play here?

Comment: Why are we using `atoi()` on a float? Or better yet: Why are we storing floating point numbers as strings?

Comment: Ah sorry about all the noise, I had an intermediate step that was converting the int into a float and when floats go past 1000000, C++ automatically scientific notations them, and basically the . was killing the atoi. Switching to atof fixes this.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::istringstream` or `strtod` which allow you to check conversion failure?

Answer (score 1):

From your edit:
The contents of mystring are "3.24552e+06" , i.e. a scientific (floating-point) string representation for the number 3245520.
Therefore, atoi parses the first integer it finds in mystring, as expected, which is: 3.
If mystring contained "3245520", your atoi call would return the integer 3245520.